# Anylogic: Time Measurement by condition

Tags: anylogic

I use several TimeMeasureStart and TimeMeasureEnd blocks in my model. Now I would like to set a condition that the TimeMeasureStart only starts measuring the time of an agent, if a certain condition is true. For example: If variable var1 == 1. In this case, var1 is a variable outside of the agent. Is it possible to set a condition "on enter" of the TimeMeasureStart block like in the screenshot below? I don't know how to replace the "????" in the condition.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should simply bypass the`TimeMeasureStart` block with a `SelectOutout` block upstream that filters agent by the condition you need:

[image]

In the SelectOutput condition, you define your condition similar to below (here, if `var1==1` agents would be measured):
[image]